# Bad choice of path in maximum-flow algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, network-flow

I'm currently studying the maximum-flow algorithm and encountered the following problem:
[image]
The number on each edge is the capacity. I wonder what kind of bad choice can cause so many iterations. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets note the two middle vertices $a$ (the upper one) and $b$ (the lower one).
Take the path $sabt$. We can push one unit of flow. Now take the path $sbat$. We can also push one unit of flow because arc $ab$ have a flow of 1.
Now that we have emptied the arc $ab$, we can again take the path $sabt$, and push one unit of flow. If we continue to take alternately the paths $sabt$ and $sbat$, we will need to take $sabt$ $10^k$ times and $sbat$ $10^k$ times to saturate the arcs.

Comment: Why can we take sbat? Isn't the edge from a to b, and not from b to a?

Comment: In an augmenting path, we are allowed to take an arc in the backward direction if there is some flow going through this arc. Once you find an augmenting path, the flow you can push through it is computed by taking the minimum over : $c_{i,j}-f_{i,j}$ for edges taken in the forward direction , and $f_{i,j}$ in the edge is taken in the backward direction. On the edges taken forward, we add the pushed flow, and on edge taken in the backward direction, we remove the pushed flow. It can be easily verified that it keeps a valid flow. $c_{i,j}$ and $f_{i,j}$ are capacity and flow on arc $(i,j)$.

Comment: Such backward arcs are forward arcs in the auxiliary (also called "residual") graph $D_f$.